# Is there a way to show the step by step computation of a calculation in Java?

Tags: java, android, math, arithmetic-expressions, operations

I am currently building an Android app that has a calculator that not only shows the result, but also shows how it reached that result?

Is there any library or any way that I could show a step by step computation for the result of the code below?

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6
int c = 7;
int d = 8;

int result = a + (b * c) / d;
```

edit: By the way, it's a calculator for physics so I have lots of formulas. I'm using exp4j to parse a string formula as an expression. Here's a sample

```
//For formula velocity = (finalVelocity - initialVelocity) / time
String formula1 = "(finalVelocity - initialVelocity) / time";
Double result1 = new ExpressionBuilder(formula)
                     .variables("finalVelocity", "initialVelocity", "time")
                     .build()
                     .setVariable("finalVelocity", 4);
                     .setVariable("initialVelocity", 2);
                     .setVariable("time", 2)
                     .evaluate();
//Sample Output
//velocity = (4 - 2) / 2
//velocity = 2 /2 
//velocity = 1

//For formula finalVelocity = (velocity * time) + initialVelocity
String formula2 = "(velocity * time) + initialVelocity";
Double result12 = new ExpressionBuilder(formula)
                     .variables("velocity", "time" "initialVelocity")
                     .build()
                     .setVariable("velocity", 4);
                     .setVariable("time", 2)
                     .setVariable("initialVelocity", 0)
                     .evaluate();
//Sample Output
//finalVelocity = (4 * 2) + 0
//finalVelocity = 8 + 0
//finalVelocity = 8
```

With many formulas, I'm trying to eliminate printing each step per formula. I'm trying to find a way to have a function that would print the steps for any formula.

Comment: Do you want specifically this result, or do you want it to be a general for any arithmetic calculation?

Comment: For any arithmetic calculation

Comment: Please add sample input and output.

Comment: I've added a sample above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you will be using *BODMAS* to solve that problem, you could consider simply printing each step:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;
int c = 7;
int d = 8;
int ans = (b * c);
System.out.println(ans)
ans /= d;
System.out.println(ans)
ans += a;
System.out.println(ans)
```

To do this, you can build a function which searches for brackets first and solves the equations in the according to *BODMAS(Brackets first, then Division, then Multiplication, then Addition, and finally Subtraction)*.
Considering you take the equation as a string, you first search for (), then solve `/` and print answers followed by `*`, `+` and `-`.

Comment: This was my initial solution. I'm currently trying this one out but it's not working for me. Well anyway, there might just be something wrong in my logic. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like this does not answer the question since the OP in answer to my question indicated that he wanted a general solution for general calculations. This requires you to write new code for every calculation separately...

Comment: @Brick Did you read what I have written beneath the code? I suggested creating a function which can handle all equations.